# Using Lists as method arguments

Tags: c#, list, methods, arguments

I am making a basic city builder game (in console). I am having a problem    with a method (DrawMap). I cant get the lists to work as input arguments to the method. I get a whole bunch of errors, so here is the code.

EDIT: It works now, thank you kmatyaszek.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace City
{
    public class map
    {
        public int m { get; set; } //Map size
        public List<int> info { get; set; }
        public List<int> fire { get; set; }
        public List<int> police { get; set; }
        public List<int> education { get; set; }
        public List<int> health { get; set; }
        public List<int> cursor { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            map map1 = new map();
            map1.m = 256;

            map1.info = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < map1.m; i++)
            {
                map1.info.Add(0);
            }

            map1.fire = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < map1.m; i++)
            {
                map1.fire.Add(0);
            }
            map1.police = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < map1.m; i++)
            {
                map1.police.Add(0);
            }
            map1.education = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < map1.m; i++)
            {
                map1.education.Add(0);
            }
            map1.health = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < map1.m; i++)
            {
                map1.health.Add(0);
            }
            map1.cursor = new List<int>() { 0, 0 };

            DrawMap(map1.info, map1.cursor);
        }

        static void DrawMap(List<int> map1.info, List<int> map1.cursor)
        {
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < Math.Sqrt(map1.m); k++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(map1.cursor[j], map1.cursor[k]);       

            for (int j = 0; j < Math.Sqrt(map1.m); j++)
            {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(map1.cursor[j], map1.cursor[k]);  
            Console.Write("A");  
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to share this bunch of errors? Does it have something to do with the parameters odds the `DrawMaps` method?

Comment: why are you having variable names like map1.info??  it is an illegal variable name in c#

Comment: @DanHunex It is part of the map1 object. And it seems to work just fine now.

Comment: You cannot declare variables like that. But when you call the method you can pass it like that

Comment: @DanHunex Well it seems to work flawlessly. How should I do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

You should read about C# methods (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx).

I think that method `DrawMap` should take `map` object:

```
...
map1.health = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < map1.m; i++)
        {
            map1.health.Add(0);
        }
        map1.cursor = new List<int>() { 0, 0 };

        DrawMap(map1);
    }

    static void DrawMap(map map1)
    {
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < Math.Sqrt(map1.m); k++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(map1.cursor[j], map1.cursor[k]);

            for (j = 0; j < Math.Sqrt(map1.m); j++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(map1.cursor[j], map1.cursor[k]);
                Console.Write("A");
            }
        }
    }
...
```

In `DrawMap` you declare two locals (j and k) in the same scope. You can't do that.

Here you can read about local variable and scope:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/samng/2007/11/09/local-variable-scoping-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where to begin. Let's start with the parameters of the `DrawMap` method. C# does not allow `.` in variable names. When you declare the signature of a method you write only names for the parameters. Don't try to reference existing variables in your program. Just choose a name. The compiler will know quick list you mean when you pass them in the call of the method:

```
DrawMap(map1.info, map.cursor);
```

After you have given proper names for the parameters of your method like this:

```
static void DrawMap(List<int> info,  List<int> cursor)
```

You can use the names inside the scope of the method.

The second thing is that you declare your index variables in the method twice. Look at your for-loop declaration. There you have `int k=0; k<...` that means that a new variable with the same name is declared. Just delete the two variables above the loops.